# How to subdivide and group a bibliography by year of publication?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=archaeologie]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcounter{BIBnumberYEARcount}
\setcounter{BIBnumberYEARcount}{1}
 \defbibenvironment{BIBnumberYEAR}
   {\list
   {\theBIBnumberYEARcount\thinspace\textbar\stepcounter{BIBnumberYEARcount}\relax}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
   {\endlist}
   {\item}


\DeclareSortingTemplate{dnymdt}{
 \sort{
   \field{presort}
 }
 \sort[final]{
   \field{sortkey}
 }
 \sort[direction=ascending]{
   \field{sortyear}
   \field{year}
   \literal{9999}
 }
 \sort[direction=ascending]{
   \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
   \literal{99}
 }
 \sort[direction=ascending]{
   \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
   \literal{99}
 }
 \sort{
 \field{pubstate}
 }
 \sort{
 \field{sortshorthand}
     \field{shorthand}
     \field{sortname}
     \field{author}
     \field{editor}
     \field{translator}
 }
 \sort{
 \field{sorttitle}
 \field{title}
 }
 \sort[direction=ascending]{
   \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
   \literal{9999}
 }
}

\begin{document}
{\begin{refcontext}[sorting=dnymdt]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=BIBnumberYEAR,
heading = none]
\end{refcontext}}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the year of the publication printed in the line above of the first entry (of many entries) which was published in that year.
Only if the year differs to the previous year it should be printed in the separate line.

e.g.

> 2004
>
> 1|       A. Author, ... 2004
>
> 2|       B. Buther, .... 2004
>
> 2005
>
> 3|       C. Author, ....2005
>
> 2006
>
> 4|       A. Author, ....2006
>
> 5|       D. Duther, ....2006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit fiddly to add content "above" the enumeration label. Once that is possible the actual code simply uses `\iffieldequals` and `\savefield` (similarly to how the `dashed` option is implemented or the compression in the `-comp` cite styles).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=archaeologie]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcounter{BIBnumberYEARcount}
\setcounter{BIBnumberYEARcount}{1}
\makeatletter
\defbibenvironment{BIBnumberYEAR}
   {\list
   {\iffieldequals{year}{\lcbbx@lastyear}
      {}
      {\makebox[0pt][l]{%
         \parbox[b]{20pt}{\leavevmode
           \printfield{year}\\}}%
       \savefield{year}{\lcbbx@lastyear}}%
    \theBIBnumberYEARcount\thinspace\textbar
    \stepcounter{BIBnumberYEARcount}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}
   {\endlist}
   {\item}
\makeatother

\DeclareSortingTemplate{dnymdt}{
 \sort{
   \field{presort}
 }
 \sort[final]{
   \field{sortkey}
 }
 \sort[direction=ascending]{
   \field{sortyear}
   \field{year}
   \literal{9999}
 }
 \sort[direction=ascending]{
   \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
   \literal{99}
 }
 \sort[direction=ascending]{
   \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
   \literal{99}
 }
 \sort{
 \field{pubstate}
 }
 \sort{
 \field{sortshorthand}
     \field{shorthand}
     \field{sortname}
     \field{author}
     \field{editor}
     \field{translator}
 }
 \sort{
 \field{sorttitle}
 \field{title}
 }
 \sort[direction=ascending]{
   \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
   \literal{9999}
 }
}

\begin{document}
{\begin{refcontext}[sorting=dnymdt]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=BIBnumberYEAR,
heading = none]
\end{refcontext}}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the first page of the MWE]

Comment: perfect, thank you! All further modifications (size, shape of the field `year`) I can do myself.